# Where can I get the dataset of duplicates questions in Stack Overflow?

Tags: dataset

Where can I get the dataset of duplicates questions in Stack Overflow? 
Maybe somewhere in: https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

Comment: Now you can ask your question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com. There also exists https://opendata.stackexchange.com. I suppose you could use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) for small partial dumps: there are the `PostLinks` table in it.